# Skype4Py Check If Group Chat

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

is there a way to check if a chat is a group chat? Or at least to find out how many users there are in a group.

Like by checking for the user number, if it is 2, then it is obviously 1-1 (Single), but if it as anything else, it would be a group chat.

Comment: http://skype4py.sourceforge.net/doc/html/

Answer (score 0):

The `Type` property of the chat object will be either `chatTypeDialog` or `chatTypeMultiChat` with the latter being a group chat. You can safely ignore the other legacy enumeration values.

Comment: Sorry for not being good at python, but how would I go on to checking this?

Comment: If you can't figure out how to check the value of a simple property, I'll recommend you read a Python 101 beginners tutorial.

Comment: Well I tried if Message.Chat.Type == Skype4Py.chatTypeMultiChat but the code hangs and never runs

Comment: confirmed: `message.Chat.Type` always hangs and eventually the connection to Skype is lost

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight modification of a code that I wrote for another question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176009/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-a-group-conversation-with-skype4py-in-python/17176358#17176358) The following code checks if there are any Group chats in either the open chats or the bookmarked chats. You should pass in a `topic` to find a chat of that topic.

```
def checkGroupChat(topic=""):
    """
    Checks if a group exists.
    """
    import Skype4Py as skype
    skypeClient = skype.Skype()
    skypeClient.Attach()
    for elem in skypeClient.ActiveChats:  # Looks in active chats and returns True if chat is found.
        if len(elem.Members) > 2 and elem.Topic == topic:
            return True

    for chat in skypeClient.BookmarkedChats: # Looks in Bookmarked Chats.
        if chat.Topic == topic:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: How about to check for the current chat, or the chat that a message was sent from

Comment: Hi! The `skypeClient.ActiveChats` part takes care of that, if you have a message and want to identify the chat from that, then, you can do minor modifications to the above code.

Comment: Ok then how would I modify it?

Comment: Can you tell me what you can use to uniquely identify a chat?

Comment: Chat blob? Title? Latest Message?

Comment: I want it to be able to check if it is an admin in a group chat and then carry commands from there

Comment: You want to go through all of the Active / Bookmarked Group chats and see which one of those has an admin and then carry out your commands, am I right?

Comment: When you say 'which one of those has an admin', what do you mean? If you mean send command /get role in each chat group and if it is MASTER, etc, carry out a command, then yes.

Otherwise.. ?????

Maybe I could use a chat blob to check

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def on_message(message, status):
    len(message.Chat.Members) > 2:
        # this is a private chat

s = Skype4Py.Skype()
s.OnMessageStatus = on_message
s.Attach()
```

`message.Chat.Type` always hanged for me and then after some seconds the connection to Skype is lost. Seems to be a bug